# Low Level Pointer Handling By OS 

Tags: c, pointers, operating-system

How are pointers handled by an operating system?

Do they get intercepted first or do the pointers access memory directly from a function call in C for example?

EDIT:

When a runtime executes a process and the process currently executes a pointer, does the Kernel immediately link to the segment or is there a layer between that intercepts the function call, and after completing whatever it did, access the data?

IF so, is anyone aware of the source code that is responsible for actually doing this, e.g. handling virtual memory pointers.

Comment: I dont see why this is downvoted. I dont face a problem.

Comment: @Helium3 You have to admit that it's a somewhat vague question, especially in its original form. So maybe that's it, or maybe it's that it "does not show any research." As for facing a problem, the [faq] states that: *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.* Any of those might be a reason for a downvote.

Answer (score 3):

The pointers in C are pointing to [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) addresses.

The OS (combined with HW usually) checks if the address you want to access is valid (in the process virtual memory domain), and if it is - it translates it to [physical address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_address).

The HW also checks if the address is already stored in [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) (if the system has CPU-cache), and if it is - it avoids reading from RAM (since it is slow), and reads directly from cache.

There is really much more to it - how exactly it is done can be covered during several academic courses - but these are the basics of the basics.

Comment: @PaulR: True, but most modern systems I am aware of, are. If there is no virtual memory, the scheme is also correct, with the identity function to extract the physical address: `getPhysical(virtual)=virtual`. Since the OP didn't mention specific system - I assumed he is looking for general explanation in the general case. IMHO, focusing only the machine level misses the point here:\ I did add an indication that cache doesn't always exist.

Comment: The reason I ask is that I want to write an idea I have related to memory randomization for security. Im assuming it is done on a C level, but the focus is in OSX and iOS(probably a stripped down or similar technique as OSX) Where would one find the actual source code for pointer handling?

Comment: It's not the general case though if you assume VM, caches, etc - the OP was just asking about pointers and mentioned no specific OS. It's probably better to just say that a pointer is a machine address and leave it at that, rather than making assumptions and thereby limiting the generality of the answer.

Comment: Sorry - I've removed the comment about "overwhelming a noob" - the question seemed very basic in nature, hence my incorrect assumption.

Comment: @PaulR - Sorry that the question seemed simple, but I think I stated it clearly. Its not that simple actually. I want to write something for memory randomization by intercepting all pointers and handling them with my code. I am aware of virtual memory etc. I dont see why you would assume.

Comment: You should probably add this information to the question, since the question as it stands sounds like a noob question asking about how pointers work. Also tag with the operating system(s) that you are interested in for more specific details.

Comment: @PaulR - True, the first sentence. The second - "Do they get intercepted first or do the pointers access memory directly from a function call in C for example?" is a pretty simply formatted question clearly asking if the system actually intercepts a pointer to do whatever it needs before and then linking to the segment. I dont see why I am even in a position to defend against people on SO. Its a community, sharing knowledge, driving technology forward, together. :)

Comment: I think that's where my noob assumption came from, since pointers don't get "intercepted" by the OS - they are just (physical or virtual) addresses. This suggests a fundamental misunderstanding of the relationship between the hardware and the OS. The better you state your question, particularly with respect to the technical level that you are asking about, the better the answers you will get.

Comment: @PaulR - How can it be a misunderstanding. Pointers must be intercepted before e.g. redirecting to virtual memory. So that's an interception. I was just asking to understand how EXACTLY in actual source code the OS handles the translation of the pointer to VM, before passing it to the MMU. I know text based communication is hell to transfer information but seriously.

Comment: I think that's where you are confused - the *hardware* handles this translation from virtual to physical addresses when a pointer is dereferenced, not the OS.

Comment: @PaulR - I guess I need to check through kernel source code, because I have an idea for memory randomization and it has to be possible to insert this into a system if it doesnt currently exist/

Comment: Since you say you're interested in OS X and iOS then check out the Darwin sources for this - you should be able to find the MMU and page table setup code plus various VM stuff like handling page faults etc.

Answer (score 2):

> How are pointers handled by an operating system?

A pointer is just an address in memory. The only reason that an operating system gets involved in "handling" a pointer is when the OS provides virtual memory. In that case, the memory management unit will take care of mapping an address in the virtual memory space to a physical address. If the pointer points to a location in the virtual memory space that's not available, the MMU generates a page fault and the OS steps in to swap in the page with the requested address. This all happens at a low level, though, and in a properly-functioning system you can  ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where would I find the source code that executes these virtual memory related functions? I want to use a stripped down linux OS and read the source code and be able to modify it and recompile the system. Do you have any advice on this please? :)

Comment: @Helium3 Start with a textbook on operating systems and computer architecture. You'll want to understand the idea behind the code before you jump in. Then read [*Understanding the Linux Virtual Memory Manager*](http://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/pdf/understand.pdf).

Comment: That link is EXACTLY what I am after. Thanks!